# how separate number in sql oracle per column

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm very frustrated, how to separate number per column data in sql oracle,
for example:

```sql
select 5.5 from dual;
```

```
|5.5|
```

but how I want output like this:

```
|5.5|         |1|   |1|   |1|   |1|   |1|   |0.5|
```

so I want data for separate that number by 1, 
but if have leftover data for example 0.5
so that data to be separate data also.

example:

--create table
CREATE TABLE EXAMPLE 
(NUMBERS NUMBER);

--insert data
INSERT INTO EXAMPLE (NUMBERS) VALUES ('5.5');

and how the query to make separate that data ?

Comment: Add some more sample data and also show us that result.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement?  This would be best handled in your application layer (e.g. C# or Java).

Comment: What about 0, and negative numbers?

Comment: Not sure how you could do this in basic SQL, but if you have permission to write functions, you could quite easily cobble together a PLSQL function that takes a number and returns an output like this, then just call that function in your query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
with 
  n as (select row_number() over (order by null) rn, numbers num from example),
  r as (select rn, level lvl, num, 
               case when num < level then mod(num, level - 1) else 1 end as val
          from n 
          connect by level <= ceil(num) 
            and prior rn = rn and prior sys_guid() is not null)
select * from r
  pivot (max(val) for lvl in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)) 
  order by rn
```

**<sup>[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=29e321a40429b28693fe316e95579649)</sup>**

It would be nice to have some unique id in your table. If you have not it, generate it automatically, here with `row_number()`.

Then you can use hierarchical query creating rows until level reaches `numbers`.

You can stop here, with values in separate rows, or pivot data, but Oracle needs to know the exact number of columns (unless you accept xml solution), so here I specified 10 columns maximum.

Works for positive numbers.

Comment: And 2 big thumbs up for your connect by clause.